# What is the word for attending a party without being invited?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for "attend a party or event without being invited"? I read it some time back but can not recollect it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

*[Gatecrashing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gatecrash)* is the most common term I've heard:

> To attend a social event without having been invited, or without having paid.

Comment: @Anji http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gatecrashing?p

Comment: ...typically abbreviated to `crashing` (as several answered below).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think anyone I know actually uses gatecrashing. They just say crashing. But I do believe this is the origin.

Comment: @MrHen Gatecrashing is quite commonly used in the circles I keep.

Comment: @shinynewbike Thank you. That's the word I was searching for.

Comment: @MrHen, David, UK/US difference maybe? I (UK) would tend to say gatecrashing.

Comment: @Benjol - Almost certainly. The OP is from India and both of you are from the UK. This aging American had never before heard of this term. Seeing the title, I came here with half a mind to DV what I thought was such an obvious answer: *party crasher* (instead I learned something from this one and had to UV that one to keep it in the running ;)

Answer (score 33):

The term I hear most often is *crash*:

> We're going to crash the party
>
> We're here to crash the party!
>
> Let's crash the party...

My local dictionary offers this:

> crash — [informal] enter (a party) without an invitation or permission.

Comment: Doesn't the term "party crasher" have a negative connotation of ruining the event?  Uninvited guests don't always have negative intentions (e.g., anonymous socializing).

Comment: Whether somebody gatecrashing or 'crashing' a party ruins it is probably more down to their actions once they arrive and the host's view on the matter than the mere fact they arrived uninvited. Although social etiquette would probably dictate that any uninvited guests are inherently unwelcome.

Comment: No - a crasher is just someone who attends without an invitation.

Comment: I also thought it had a negative connotation of ruining the event. @Randolf

Comment: @Rory Alsop:  Back in the 1980s when University students planned to "crash a party" they had bad intentions to be disruptive.  Although I see that a definition of "crash" includes the meaning you mentioned, I've never heard it used this way before.  Interesting (+1 for you).

Comment: I've never heard it used for anything other than showing up without being invited.

Comment: I think a lot of the negative connotations of "crashing a party" have to do with the fact that if someone attends a party uninvited, and *is not* disruptive, it doesn't provide anything to talk about. Non-disruptive party crashing may very well be a silent majority.

Answer (score 5):

That person would be characterized as an "interloper".

Comment: That's a good one, but I think the OP is looking for a verb. Make sure your answer hits the point of the question.

Comment: Easy then, **interlope**!

Comment: I think interloper is someone who interferes in another person's conversation.

Comment: @Daronte Thank you. I was asking about the act of attending a party or event without being called. Anyways I got to know one more word :)

Answer (score 2):

"Uninvited guest" seems to be a good description for such an *obtrusion*, although it is two words (could that work for you?).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have a negative connotation. When I've heard people use the expression, or when I've said it myself, it generally just means to show up spontaneously. Perhaps the connotation has changed over the past decade or so; I remember equating it with party-ruining some time long ago. Perhaps it still has the negative connotation, but now people are using it ironically to mean that they're showing up without invitation but that they aren't going to destroy the place in stereotypical teen movie fashion.

Comment: @strangeronyourtrain:  I believe "uninvited guest" is fairly close to neutral, although slightly down on the negative side because "uninvited" would be more likely to represent a potential "inconvenience" (e.g., not enough beer for every attendee).

Comment: @strangeronyourtrain:  Perhaps there are different localized expectations in play?  If I was organizing a party and I found out that someone was planning to "be a party crasher" (as I suspect is the term you're referring to), my immediate mental image would be of some jerks sneaking into the party, pushing guests around, knocking over furniture, throwing food and drinks, and even vandalizing the facility (e.g., ripping down curtains, damaging furniture, smashing windows, punching holes in the walls, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a word to describe the person who is attending uninvited, or are you looking for a word to describe the act of attending a party uninvited?

One who attends a party uninvited could be committing a "faux pas", which means a "violation of social norms or etiquette."

But the words that can be used for describing a *person* who commits these types of social blunders are plentiful... depending on how harsh or kind you are looking to be in portraying the person's wrongdoing.

To *tag-along* to a party uninvited might work.  *Crash* the party also works beautifully.

Comment: ...but, a Douglas Adams' story character (such as **Zaphod Beeblebrox**) _could_ be a "faux pas."  ;-)

Comment: @Rachel thank you. The word I was looking for is 'gatecrash'

Answer (score -2):

Intruder may be the choice you are looking for. I guess there are many more words you can use for it.

Comment: Hi user134427, welcome to the site! Can you please add a reference to comply with site conventions? It will make your answer more useful for readers in the future.